# Как вывести категории соответствующие каталогу?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

У меня есть три модели:

```
class Catalog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Название каталога')
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)


class Category(models.Model):
    catalog = models.ForeignKey(Catalog, verbose_name='Каталог', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Название категории')
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)


class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name='Категория', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Наименование')
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)
```

Есть Каталог(например "Для мужчин", "Для женщин"), есть категории(например "Для мужчин"-> Брюки, футболки и т.д., "Для женщин"-> Брюки, футболки и т.д.). Как при добавление товара, сделать так чтобы при выборе каталога, категории соответствовали этому каталогу, а не вываливались все существующие категории? Все это должно быть в админке django.

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов:

создаешь форму, которая принимает параметром текущий каталог

```
class EditProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        edit_catalog = kwargs.pop("catalog", None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['category'].queryset = Category.objects.filter(catalog=edit_catalog)
```

И во view создаешь ее. У тебя view для добавления товара должна получать id каталога.

```
def edit_product_view(request, id_catalog):
   catalog = Catalog.objects.get(pk=id_catalog)
   form = EditProductForm(request.POST or None, catalog=catalog)
   if request.POST:
     if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        HttpResponseRedirect('...')
   return render("template_name.html", {'form': form})
```

ну и не забываешь добавить urlconfig до этой страницы с параметром id_catalog

```
urlpatterns += [
    ...
    path(r'edit-product/catalog-<int:id_catalog>/', edit_product_view, name='edit-product'),
    ...
]
```

либо можно при в форму редактирования товара добавить еще один селект для выбора каталога. И с помощью [django_select2](https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) организовать зависимые(`dependent_fields` в `django_select2`) селекты. Когда значения для одного из селектов подбираются на основании других полей формы

Comment: Во-первых, спасибо за ответ. Во-вторых, я может что-то не понял, но как мне сделать чтоб это в админке было?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56476261/7186864 тут указано как добавить кастомные view  к admin интерфейсу, кнопку которая ведет на эту вью можно расположить на странице редактирования карточки Catalog. Либо использовать другой вариант, через цепочку зависимых селектов.(обновил в ответе)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я но я пошел другим путем.